# Reading from binary as float(4 bytes per number) to csv file

Tags: python

I would like to read from a binary as float values and write them to a csv file, which almost works with the code below. The thing is struct.unpack is writing the float value like:

> (number,)

and I would like to write it without the paranteses,().

Is there a better way to get the values as a float instead of using unpack or what do you suggest?

```
count = 0
output_file = open(r"C:\Users\heltbork\Desktop\binTocsvDirect\00000006.txt", "w")

with open(r"C:\Users\heltbork\Desktop\binTocsvDirect\00000006.bin", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        byte = f.read(4)
        if not byte:
            break
        output_file.write(str(unpack('f', byte)))
        count = count + 1
        if count == 6:
            count = 0
            output_file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a string form of a `tuple`.

```
unpack(...)
```

Gives back a `tuple`.This is stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

> ... The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item.

If you want the first element:

```
first = unpack('f', byte)[0]
```

In your code, use:

```
output_file.write(str(unpack('f', byte)[0]))
```

Tip: Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).